# Elementwise operation on pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas Series `x` with values `1`, `2` or `3`.

I want it to have values `monkey`, `gorilla`, and `tarzan` depending on the values.

I guess I should do something like

```
values = ['monkey', 'gorilla', 'tarzan']

x = values[x - 1]
```

but it doesn't work. I guess it's because it doesn't operate elementwisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use maping by `dict` with function [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
print (s)  
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

d = {1:'monkey',2:'gorilla',3:'tarzan'}
print (s.map(d))
0     monkey
1    gorilla
2     tarzan
dtype: object
```